# Why does adding an array to number return a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, addition

```
var array = [1,2,4];

array+1  //gives '1,2,41'.
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone explain this behaviour?

This answer attempts to explain this behavior *from the point of view of spec*.

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation), during the run-time evaluation of `+`, both expressions (left and right) are converted to their primitive values.

> 7. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
> 8. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).

[toPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive) tries to pass `hint:number` (since invoked during *arithmetic evaluation*) to *OrdinaryToPrimitive*

> 3. If hint is "string", then
>      a. Let methodNames be «"toString", "valueOf"».
> 4. Else,
>      b. Let methodNames be «"valueOf", "toString"». //this gets invoked

Since one of the values were **casted to string via 4a)** above, *string concatenation takes place*.

Hence

`[1,2,4] + 1` => `[1,2,4].toString() + "1"` => `"1,2,4" + "1"` => (finally) `"1,2,41"`

Comment: I loved how you pulled exact place when that is happening an why. I know why it does so but I never thought about looking where is that written in such a manner. +1

Comment: @DanteTheSmith Thanks

Comment: @gurvinder372 Edited your question to match the OP's example, and +1 from me :)

Comment: @KobyDouek Thanks, didn't notice that earlier.

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372 .. much helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Array is casted to string - then concatenated with integer value which is also casted to string.

Comment: Sorry,but that was neither explanatory not informative.

Comment: How? It describes what happens, that an explanation. And the informative part is now you know it. A bit short and simple answer but it's on point.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `+` sign with a declared javascipt object (`var array`), even if one of the elements is a number, it doesn't perform an **arithmetic** addition operation - it **concatenates** the values as two **strings**.

In your example, your array `[1,2,4]` is being casted into a string with a value of `1,2,4`. So `1,2,4` concatenated with `1` is `1,2,41`

Comment: Except when you don't declare that object first `{} + 1` equals `1`  but `var obj = {}; obj + 1` will equal `"[object Object]1"` and `{} + {} + 1` equals `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect? [2,3,5]?

You haven't wrote a mutator for array, you added 1 to array (which is an object). Why do you expect for object to be able to add 1 to it?

JS figured out you need a primitive from that object and listed that object into a string. Now it knows how to "add" 2 strings (precisely its concatenate) so it did.

If you expected an entire array to get +1 on all elements. You  want:

```
for (var i=array .length; i--;) {
    array [i]++;
}
```

Or

```
array = array.map(function(e) {return '#' + e});
```

Or in ES6 and beyond arrow function with map

```
array = array.map(i => i + 1);
```

Comment: Question was purely regarding the behaviour not on pushing the value in the array nor adding it to each element. Thanks for the effort anyway

Answer (score 0):

When the operands of an operator are different types, they will be converted to a common type.

Both an array and a Number can be converted to string, this is called **coercion**.

If you would like to add `1` to an array, you can do this:

```
var array = [1,2,4];
array.push(1);
```